# Join on a fragment of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to join a fragment of a dataframe with another one. The structure of the dataframe to join is simplified below:

```
left:
ID    f1   TIME
1     10     1
3     10     1
7     10     1
9     10     2
2     10     2
1     10     2
3     10     2

right:
ID    f2    f3
1      0    11
7      9    11
```

I need to select the left dataset by time, and I need to attached the right one, the result I would like to have is the following:

```
left:
ID    f1   TIME  f2     f3
1     10     1    0     11
3     10     1  nan    nan
7     10     1    9     11
9     10     2  nan    nan
2     10     2  nan    nan
1     10     2  nan    nan
3     10     2  nan    nan
```

Currently I am usually joining dataframes in this way:

```
left = left.join(right.set_index('ID'), on='ID')
```

In this case I am using:

```
left[left.TIME == 1] = left[left.TIME == 1].join(right.set_index('ID'), on='ID')
```

I have also tried with merge, but the result is the left dataframe without any of the other columns.
Finally the structure of my script need to do this for every unique TIME in the dataframe, thus:

```
 for t in numpy.unique(left.TIME):
     #do join on the fragment left.TIME == t
```

If I save the returned value from the join function in a new dataframe everything works fine, but trying to add the value at the left dataframe does not work.

EDIT: The IDs of the left dataset can be present multiple times, but not inside the same TIME value.

Comment: I think this is typo, `left = left.right(right.set_index('ID'), on='ID')`, need `left = left.join(right.set_index('ID'), on='ID')`

Comment: can't you just do `pd.merge(left, right, how='left, on='ID')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter first by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `merge` and [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) last:

```
df1 = left[left['TIME']==1]
#alternative
#df1 = left.query('TIME == 1')
df2 = left[left['TIME']!=1]
#alternative
#df2 = left.query('TIME != 1')

df = pd.concat([df1.merge(right, how='left'), df2])
print (df)
   ID  TIME  f1   f2    f3
0   1     1  10  0.0  11.0
1   3     1  10  NaN   NaN
2   7     1  10  9.0  11.0
3   9     2  10  NaN   NaN
4   2     2  10  NaN   NaN
5   1     2  10  NaN   NaN
6   3     2  10  NaN   NaN
```

EDIT: `merge` create default indices, so possible solution is create column first and then set to index:

```
print (left)
    ID  f1  TIME
10   1  10     1
11   3  10     1
12   7  10     1
13   9  10     2
14   2  10     2
15   1  10     2
16   3  10     2

#df = left.merge(right, how='left')
df1 = left[left['TIME']==1]

df2 = left[left['TIME']!=1]
df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index().merge(right, how='left').set_index('index'), df2])
print (df)
    ID  TIME  f1   f2    f3
10   1     1  10  0.0  11.0
11   3     1  10  NaN   NaN
12   7     1  10  9.0  11.0
13   9     2  10  NaN   NaN
14   2     2  10  NaN   NaN
15   1     2  10  NaN   NaN
16   3     2  10  NaN   NaN
```

EDIT:

After discussion after modify input data is possible use:

```
df = left.merge(right, how='left', on=['ID','TIME'])
```

Comment: This is working, however, the result is changing the index of the row, is it possible to keep the same index of left? @jezrael

Comment: The second method give me that error: cannot insert ID, already exists @jezrael

Comment: How working `df1.reset_index().merge(right, how='left').set_index('index')` ? Same error?

Comment: `ID` is index or column?

Comment: Is the same as before, where should I put it? @jezrael

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169148/discussion-between-guido-muscioni-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
res = left.drop_duplicates('ID')\
          .merge(right, how='left')\
          .append(left[left.duplicated(subset=['ID'])])

#    ID  TIME  f1   f2    f3
# 0   1     1  10  0.0  11.0
# 1   3     1  10  NaN   NaN
# 2   7     1  10  9.0  11.0
# 3   9     2  10  NaN   NaN
# 4   2     2  10  NaN   NaN
# 5   1     2  10  NaN   NaN
# 6   3     2  10  NaN   NaN
```

Note that columns `f2` and `f3` become `float` since `NaN` is considered a float.

Comment: maybe I forgot to specify one thing, ID can be present multiple time I have updated the question example.

Comment: it should be fine now @jpp

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni, see update - though not clear this is precisely what you want.